# Using QSet and CRTP in C++ module

Tags: c++, qt, c++-modules

I'm trying to convert some of my C++ code base from using header files to using modules.

Here is a `.h`/`.cpp` pair that compiles and works:

```cpp
// Graph.h
#pragma once
#include <QSet>

template<class NodeT>
struct GraphTypes {
   using NodeType = NodeT;
};

template<class GraphTypes> class Node;
class DefaultGraphTypes : public GraphTypes<Node<DefaultGraphTypes>> {};

template<class GraphTypes>
class Node {
   QSet<typename GraphTypes::NodeType const *> m_Sources;
};
```

```cpp
// header.cpp
#include "Graph.h"

Node<DefaultGraphTypes> TestNode;
```

I have converted this to the following `.ixx`/`.cpp` pair:

```cpp
// Graph.ixx
module;
#include <QSet>

export module Graph;

template<class NodeT>
struct GraphTypes {
   using NodeType = NodeT;
};

template<class GraphTypes> class Node;
export class DefaultGraphTypes : public GraphTypes<Node<DefaultGraphTypes>> {};

export template<class GraphTypes>
class Node {
   QSet<typename GraphTypes::NodeType const *> m_Sources;
};
```

```cpp
// module.cpp
import Graph;

Node<DefaultGraphTypes> TestNode;
```

When compiling the latter, I get an error `C2877`: `'QHash<Key,T>::Node' is not accessible from  'QHash<Key,T>'` in file `qhash.h`, line `1080`.

I've tried with a few different changes:

1. If I change `m_Sources` from `QSet` to `QVector`, it compiles and
   works.
2. If I change `m_Sources` from `QSet` to `std::set`, it compiles and
   works.
3. If I change `QSet`'s template argument from `typename GraphTypes::NodeType const *` to `Node<DefaultGraphTypes> const *`,
   it compiles and works.
4. If I change `QSet`'s template argument from `typename GraphTypes::NodeType const *` to `typename DefaultGraphTypes::NodeType const *`, it compiles and works.

What is going wrong!? I'm using Qt 5.15.10 and Visual Studio 17.4.2.

`qhash.h` line `1080` is in the class `QMultiHash<Key, T>`, which inherits from `QHash<Key, T>`:
[image]

`QHash<Key, T>::Node` looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What happens if you `#include <QSet>` in the "module.cpp" file before importing your module? Also, what happens if you change one of the `GraphTypes` to not be named the same thing as the *other* `GraphTypes`, and then disambiguate your code so you know which one you're trying to use?

Comment: `#include <QSet>` in `module.cpp` seems to do the trick!!!! Thanks!! I'll do some more testing. Feel free to make a proper answer of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @NicolBolas, the solution was to `#include <QSet>` in `module.cpp` before importing the module:

```cpp
// module.cpp
#include <QSet>
import Graph;

Node<DefaultGraphTypes> TestNode;
```